# OpenGL Depth Buffer issue

Tags: opengl, buffer, axis, depth

I am having a lot of difficulty making the depth buffer work in my openGL program. I have already Tried all the common issues like:

- Messing with my Clip Planes
- Makes the near and far z clip planes positive
- Ensuring i'm actually calling everything for the depth buffer

Here is a code snippet from my Display function to help you guys understand my problem. my Window size is 600x600, and I'm trying to have my object be displayed isographically.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glDepthRange(0.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
//isometric view
glLoadIdentity();
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glOrtho (-300, 400.0,-300, 400.0, 10, 700.0);

gluLookAt(10, 10, 10, 300.0, 300.0, 162.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
//Center of object located at (300, 300, 162)

glViewport(0, 0, 600, 600);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

//Code drawing my program
```

I can provide more of my code if any of you guys think it would be helpful. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Did you request a depth buffer for your window?

Comment: @derhass , I'm not too sure what you mean by that, could you explain?

Comment: @derhass After reading what you said, I did some research and I found my mistake. I didn't include glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH), after including this I cound my problem. Thank you for your help!